# Can't create class object in quickbooks using quickbooks ruby gem

Tags: ruby, quickbooks

I would like to create Account object for Quickbooks. However, when I try:

```
service.create(account_object)
```

It returns the error:

```
Quickbooks::InvalidModelException: Classification is not included in the list
```

I tried putting in one of the default values(https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/account), but it returns the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Classification in account will be something like Liability, Revenue, Expense or Asset etc.

Go to this URL https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Account

look at AccountType section => Child attributes

It have all list of classification and account type that we can use while creating accounts

You can use below sample code to create account

```
begin
    oauth_client = OAuth::AccessToken.new($qb_oauth_consumer, token, secret)
    service = Quickbooks::Service::Account.new(:access_token => oauth_client, :company_id => realm_id)
    new_account = Quickbooks::Model::Account.new(:name => 'Undeposited money', :account_type => 'Other Current Asset', :classification => 'Asset' )
    create_acccount = service.create(new_account)
rescue Exception => e
    # e.message will show response of quickbooks for you request 
    puts e.message
    # e.message.inspect will show logs
    puts e.backtrace.inspect  
end
```